# How to remove the rows in the following file?

Tags: string-manipulation, filtering, files-and-directories

Consider a file `file.txt` having the form

```
# First line is a grid of y; Starting from second line: first number is a, second is temperature, next is set of numbers is corresponding to f(y) on the grid
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    2.500000e-01    5.000000e-01
0.100000e+00    0.000000e+01    0.010000e+02    2.500000e-02    5.000000e-02
```

How to convert it to a form

```
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    2.500000e-01    5.000000e-01
0.100000e+00    0.000000e+01    0.010000e+02    2.500000e-02    5.000000e-02
```

which can be interpreted as numerical data?

Comment: If you know how many lines you need to skip, there is the `HeaderLines` options for many of the import formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just take out the first line

```
str = "# First line is a grid of y; Starting from second line: first number is a, second is temperature, next is set of numbers is corresponding to f(y) on the grid
0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    2.500000e-01    5.000000e-01
0.100000e+00    0.000000e+01    0.010000e+02    2.500000e-02    5.000000e-02"

(*Method 1*) StringReplace[str, Shortest[head__] ~~ "\n" ~~ rest__ :> rest]
(*Method 2*) #1 <> "\n" <> #2 & @@ Rest@StringSplit[str, "\n"] == %
```

> "0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 2.500000e-01 5.000000e-01
>   0.100000e+00 0.000000e+01 0.010000e+02 2.500000e-02 5.000000e-02"
>
> True

If there are multiples lines in the header, such as

```
str = "# First line is a grid of y;
# Starting from second line:
# first number is a
# second is temperature
# next is set of numbers is corresponding to f(y) on the grid
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 2.500000e-01 5.000000e-01
0.100000e+00 0.000000e+01 0.010000e+02 2.500000e-02 5.000000e-02";

StringReplace[str, ("#" ~~ Shortest[__] ~~ "\n") .. ~~ rest__ :> rest]
```

> "0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 2.500000e-01 5.000000e-01
>   0.100000e+00 0.000000e+01 0.010000e+02 2.500000e-02 5.000000e-02"

And if there are comments within the data, or actually **in any case**,

```
str = "# First line is a grid of y;
# Starting from second line:
# first number is a
# second is temperature
# next is set of numbers is corresponding to f(y) on the grid
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 2.500000e-01 5.000000e-01
# test comment
0.100000e+00 0.000000e+01 0.010000e+02 2.500000e-02 5.000000e-02";

StringReplace[str, ("#" ~~ Shortest[__] ~~ "\n") :> ""]
```

> "0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 2.500000e-01 5.000000e-01
>   0.100000e+00 0.000000e+01 0.010000e+02 2.500000e-02 5.000000e-02"